# How to check if a set is totally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Is the set $T=\{g_k\in C[0,1]: g_k(x)=x^k\}$ closed, open or totally bounded? $T$ here is with the sup norm.

It is clear that $T$ is bounded because for every $g_k\in T$, $\|g_k\|=1$.

$T$ also seems totally bounded because for any $\epsilon>0$, $T$ is in a finite collection of balls centered in $T$. I concluded this based on the following picture:
[image]

$T$ seems not open as from the picture there is space between $f_1$ and $f_2$ and no other element of $T$ is in between.

I am not sure about closed.

Is there any other systematic way to answer this question? I'm not sure about my conclusions from the picture. Thanks.

Comment: Show that for fixed $m$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|g_m-g_n\|=1$.  This proves that $T$ is closed and partially unbounded (= negation of totally bounded.)

Comment: @Chad K $T$ is closed?

Comment: If $T$ where totally bounded (aka precompact) in the complete metric space $C([0,1])$ then the sequence $g_k$ would have a (uniformly) convergent subsequence which is not true.

Comment: @RyeCatcher: An open ball of radius $<\frac{1}{2}$ can contain at most finitely many elements of $T$, so $T$ has no accumulation points.  Nor can it be covered by finitely many open balls of such radius.

Comment: @Jochen Can you please explain why that is true? Are you assuming T to be closed?

Comment: @ChadK Thanks a lot. I understand why T is closed and totally bounded. Why is it not open?

Comment: To elaborate my previous comment: In complete metric spaces, closures of precompact sets are compact (because they remain precompact and are complete). If $T$ were precompact then its closure would be a compact set containing the sequence $g_k$ which does not have a convergent subsequence. This argument does not use that $T$ is closed which nevertheless is true. Since $C([0,1])$ is connected (trivially, because it is a normed vector space) closedness of $T$ implies that it is not open.

Comment: @Jochen: Thanks I understand now that T is not open. But I don't understand what you mean by precompact. I understand that a precompact set is a set whose closure is compact. But you seem to be using some other definition.

Comment: The usual definition of precompactness of a set $T$ is that, for every radius, $T$ can be covered by finitely many balls of that radius. Only in complete metric spaces this implies that the closure is compact (which is the usual definition of relatively compact sets).

Comment: @Jochen I see, thanks. You probably meant the balls centered at points in the precompact set. If yes, then this is what I know as totally bounded.

Comment: It does not matter: If you can cover $T\neq\emptyset$ with $n$ balls of radius $r/2$ then you can find a cover of $T$ with $\le n$ balls of radius $r$ and centres in $T$.